# Generating Doctrine2 Entities from Zend Framework causes Helper em is not defined

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

Good Morning,

I'm new to Doctrine2 and am attempting to integrate it with Zend Framework 1.11.  I tried to generate my models using orm:generate-entities from the doctrine command line.  However, when I do this, I receive the following error:

[InvalidArgumentException]
The helper 'em' is not defined.

What steps must I follow to generate models and entities for use within ZF?

Here are the contents of bootstrap.php:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
protected function _initDoctrine(){
require_once('usr/share/pear/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php');

$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$classLoader= new usr/share/pear/Doctrine/Common('Entities',
realpath(Zend_Registry::get('config')->resources->EntityManager->connection->entities),
'LoadClass');

$autoLoader->pushAutoLoader(array($classLoader, 'LoadClass'), 'Entities');
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Repositories',
    realpath(Zend_Registry::get('config')->resources->entityManager->connection->entities), 'loadClass');



$autoloader->pushAutoloader(array($classLoader, 'loadClass'), 'Repositories');     

$em=\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($options['db'],$config);
Zend_Registry::set('em',$em);

return $em;
}
```

Thanks much for your help!

Comment: Take a look at this [library](https://github.com/guilhermeblanco/ZendFramework1-Doctrine2) it's what I'm using to integrate Doctrine and ZF

Comment: I've downloaded it.  How do I integrate it into my existing app?  (newbie to Doctrine)  Thanks:)

Comment: Hi, you may also check my resource on github, here is the documentation link: http://borisguery.github.com/bgylibrary/#bgylib-components-bgy-application-resource-doctrine2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options for you to choose from:

1.Check [zendcasts](http://www.zendcasts.com/unit-testing-doctrine-2-entities/2011/02/) which has useful screencasts and guids on how to integrate doctrine 2 and ZF 1 and how to use them to work with database manipulations and deep integration with zend_auth.make sure to check other screencasts too.check [here](http://www.zendcasts.com/index/) for full index of screencasts.

2.Buy "EASY PHP WEBSITES WITH THE ZEND FRAMEWORK" book which is a good resource for doctrine2 integration and you may access the project files for free from the address below.
in README you can find this step by step guide:
1. Clone Doctrine 2

```
$ git clone git://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2.git doctrine2-orm
```

1. Copy the following three directories into a directory named Doctrine found in the z2d2 `library` directory:

   lib/Doctrine/ORM
   lib/vendor/doctrine-common/lib/Doctrine/Common
   lib/vendor/doctrine-dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL
2. Copy the following directory into the z2d2 `library` directory:

   lib/vendor/Symfony

When done, your `library` directory should look like this:

```
library/
  Doctrine/
  Common/
  DBAL/
  ORM/
Symfony/
WJG/
```

You'll also need to modify the Doctrine database connection parameters and entity/proxy/repository paths. These parameters are all found in the `application.ini.example` file. Rename this file to `application.ini` before making your changes.

Finally, you'll need to use the included Doctrine CLI to generate the schemas, done from within the `application` directory using the following command:

```
$ ./scripts/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
```

3.Your third option will be to use Bisna project on github.README file is clear,however i suggest you read [this blog post](http://www.kurttest.com/zfa/bisna.html) too. Bisna project is probably the most powerful integration.For an example project which already incorporates bisna,check [Zend-Framework-Starter-Kit](https://github.com/nvoyageur/Zend-Framework-Starter-Kit)

```
  git clone git://github.com/nvoyageur/Zend-Framework-Starter-Kit.git
```

Comment: thamks for the advice  when I run the commnd, I receive this error:

Comment: thamks for the advice  when I run the commnd, I receive this error: PHP Warning:  require(Zend/Application.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /root/Zend/workspaces/DefaultWorkspace7/EpaySid/application/scripts/doctrine.php on line 24
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Application.php' (include_path='/root/Zend/workspaces/DefaultWorkspace7/EpaySid/library:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /root/Zend/workspaces/DefaultWorkspace7/EpaySid/application/scripts/doctrine.php on line 24
How do I rectify this?

Comment: @Sidc which option did you choose from? is your ZF globally accessible and setup in php.ini or using pear channel? try adding ZF to your php include_path.open php.ini and change ; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
 ; include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"

 to...

 ; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
 include_path = ".;c:\php\includes;c:\zend\library"                        c:\zend\library should be the path for zend library.please double check the path you enter.
...and restart the wamp server again

Comment: I chose the game nomad sample from Mr. Gilmore's book.  I'm running CentOS and have installed Zend Studio on it located at /root/Zend or something to that effect.